# Pegar Valor total com exceção de data

Tags: sql

Estou tentando desenvolver uma query que me retorne um valor total de pedidos de um determinado cliente, com uma faixa de data informada. Por exemplo, entre 05/11/2015 à 05/12/2015.

O problema é que preciso fazer a exceção de uns dias entre as datas informadas. Por exemplo, que essa query pegasse o valor entre as datas acima informadas, exceto os dias 14/11/2015 e os dias 21/11/2015.

Esses dias não poderiam ter o valor de seus pedidos adicionados no valor total.

O que eu consegui fazer foi isso:

```
select sum(p.totalValor), c.nomeCliente 
from Pedido p join Cliente c 
on c.idCliente =  p.idCliente
where p.dataPedido = /*filtro das datas*/
and idCliente = 2
```

Não consegui desenvolver a parte das datas. Tem algum jeito de fazer isso?

As tabelas estão abaixo

tabela Cliente

idCliente
NomeCliente

tabela Pedido

idPedido
idCliente
dataPedido
totalValor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para buscar um periodo de datas utilize o operador [BETWEEN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) e para excluir algumas datas utilize o operador [NOT IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

Como você está utilizando a função [SUM](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) você precisa utilizar o agrupador [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) em sua consulta.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(P.TOTALVALOR),
    C.NOMECLIENTE
FROM 
    PEDIDO P 
JOIN 
    CLIENTE C ON C.IDCLIENTE =  P.IDCLIENTE
WHERE 
    DATAPEDIDO BETWEEN '05/11/2015' AND '05/12/2015'
AND
    DATAPEDIDO NOT IN ('14/11/2015', '21/11/2015')
AND 
    IDCLIENTE = 2
GROUP BY C.NOMECLIENTE
```